Governor Limits - Concurrent Long-Running Transactions
I have a use case where I make several sync outbound calls all within the same transaction to different 3rd party systems (via Omnistudio Integration Procedure). I want to check my understanding for the below statements and if this would affect me, where it states the following two points:

"Number of synchronous concurrent transactions for long-running transactions that last longer than 5 seconds for each org."
"If more transactions are started while the 10 long-running transactions are still running, they’re denied. HTTP callout processing time isn’t included when calculating this limit."

Is this for outbound calls, inbound calls or both? Also is this specific to Apex context? Do the same limits apply in Omnistudio or Flow HTTP callouts (without Apex being called)?
To resolve this issue I see two options, either make the context async or use the Continuation class in apex. Is my understanding correct?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

To resolve this issue - you haven't told us what problem you're trying to solve, see XY Problem. Please edit your question and explain what you're trying to accomplish.

@identigral I have updated the question

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/advanced-features-of-omnistudio-integration-procedures/manage-long-running-integration-procedures covers it


"Number of synchronous concurrent transactions for long-running transactions that last longer than 5 seconds for each org."
"If more transactions are started while the 10 long-running transactions are still running, they’re denied. HTTP callout processing time isn’t included when calculating this limit."

This is for outbound calls in an Apex transaction that is executing synchronously (like a Visualforce controller, apex web services controller, LWC controller, invocable apex, ...). It would not apply to queueable, future, batchable, etc
